Issues using mDNS with Apple AirPlay
I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 and have setup a Layer 2 WiFi to Ethernet bridge using a WiFi Card in 4addr mode. When plugging in a Sonos speaker to the computer's Ethernet port, I'm able to see the speaker in my list of available airplay devices on my iPhone. When trying to connect, however, the request times out and I cannot play any music. Anyone know why this would be the case? I've installed mDNS and configured both IP Forwarding on the device and Multicast.
Thanks!
